# formating datetime field in progress-4gl

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I want to format a datetime field but i can't figure out the syntactic. I want it to display it to look like this: "mm:dd:yy hh:mm am".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
display replace( string( now, "99/99/99 hh:mm:ss am" ), "/", ":" ) format "x(20)"
```